# Direct Mapped Cache using Blocks

Tags: caching, hardware, cpu-architecture

I know this is a homework question and I am not asking for the answer. I would just like to understand this question, feel free to use other examples to explain.

The question that I need to answer is...

```
Each reference is a read of a 4-byte integer value and is described by the byte 
address of that integer.

Assuming a 1KB, 16B block, direct-mapped cache, initially empty, fill in whether 
each reference is a hit or a miss.
```

We are given a list of references that are 4 bytes. For example 0x00000000, 0x00000006, ...

From my understanding there are 64 blocks (1024/16) and each block is 16 bytes. When it looks at the first reference, it would be a miss and it would bring that into the cache. I know that it brings in the next reference in to the cache because each block would hold 16 bytes. Does this mean, on a miss, it brings in 4 references because each reference is 4 bytes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes what you have understood is correct. When a byte is read from the memory, temporal locality suggests that the next few bytes will also be subsequently read. So caches usually have block size of more than 1 reference, in this case 4 references. During the next memory access, if the processor requests the very next reference, it's already there in the cache!

The memory address can be divided into two parts: block address and block offset. The block offset will be used to choose between these references which are on the same block of the cache. The other part, block address is further divided into tag and index fields. The index field is used to choose which set to access (in case of direct mapped cache, each cache block is 1 set). The tag field chooses the cache block from within the set.

Answer (score 1):

@shailesh is right, but be careful with the word *reference*. The *reference* pattern depends on the program. Imagine the case where we write a C program that references a char array in a 16Byte stride. Here's a dumb routine that will do basically that:

```
void foo (char * x, int MAX) {
    int i;
    char a;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i += 16)
           a = x[i];
}
```

Suppose `x` is at address `0x00000000`. This loop will then reference addresses
`0x00000000`, `0x00000010`, `0x00000020`, `0x00000030`, and so on. In this case, after the very first reference to `x[0]`, `x[0]` through `x[15]` will have been brought into the cache because of the 16B block size. But the next *reference*, which is `x[16]` *has not*. In other words, for your cache here, *every* reference in this loop will result in a cache miss.

You will find that when optimizing for performance, thinking about the machine's cache organization and behavior will help you avoid poor memory access patterns like this.